# k&r example, temperature conversion

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, kernighan-and-ritchie

I'm playing around with some code in K&R just for fun but have run into an error which I can't explain myself. I'm modifying code on page 9 in section 1.2, i.e. the temperature conversion program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* converts a range of fahrenheit temperatures to celsius
and displays them in a table*/

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  float fahr, celsius;
  float lower, upper, step;

  if(argc != 4){
    printf("Usage: ./tempConvert lower upper step\n");
    return 1;
  }

  // note: atof is bad?
  lower = atof(argv[1]);   // lower limit of temperature
  upper = atof(argv[2]);   // upper limit of temperature
  step  = atof(argv[3]);   // step size

  //printf("%f %f %f",lower, upper, step);

  fahr = lower;
  printf("F \t C \n");

  while(fahr <= upper){
    celsius = 5.0*(fahr-32.0)/9.0; // if this were int, 5/9=0 because int division
    printf("%3.1f \t %6.1f\n", fahr, celsius);
    fahr += step;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

When run, I get an infinite loop. However, when I change atof to atoi, it works perfectly fine other than the fact that I wanted float precision instead of just having integers. Printing out the values right after entering them also gives garbage instead of the numbers I entered. What is causing this difference between using atoi and atof to read in numbers?

Answer (score 5):

You didn't include `<stdlib.h>`, so your compiler assumes that `atof()` returns an `int`, but it doesn't.

You aren't compiling with enough warnings enabled!  You should insist that the compiler warns you when you call a function for which there is no prototype in scope.  Note that C99 mode will warn you if there's no declaration at all for the function, but it still permits non-prototype declarations.

With GCC, I routinely use this (or `-std=c11` and the other options):

```
gcc -g -O3 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition -Wold-style-declaration -Werror ...
```

Your code would not compile under those options.

Comment: That explains it. Thank you, I didn't realize I could add in all those warnings at the same time either!